# SQL embedded in c

Tags: sql, c

Database is like:

```
table book: book_id, title

table wrote: book_id, author_id, author_order

table author: author_id, author_name
```

Every book is written by several person and have author_order.

I need to output using c program like:

```
book_id

authors: author1, author2, ... , authork

title
```

Now I'm using a cursor to fetch the book_id and title, but how to get all the authors who wrote a book?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You should read on SQL and JOIN operation in particular. It is not a C question.

Comment: At first I want to declare cursor using the values fetched by the cursor selecting book_id in the fetching loop, but found it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is pretty straightforward, all I would think you would need is a join from author to wrote to book.

```
SELECT author_id, author_name, bookid, title
  FROM author
  JOIN wrote 
    ON (author.authorid = wrote.authorid)
  JOIN book
    ON (wrote.bookid = book.bookid)
```